# How to solve "name 'mainWin' is not defined" error

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, 
QComboBox, QCompleter
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel, QStringListModel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import pandas as pd
import pickle

class ExtendedComboBox(QComboBox):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(ExtendedComboBox, self).__init__(parent)

    self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
    self.setEditable(True)

    # add a filter model to filter matching items
    self.pFilterModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
    self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
    self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(self.model())

    # add a completer, which uses the filter model
    self.completer = QCompleter(self.pFilterModel, self)
    # always show all (filtered) completions
    self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
    self.setCompleter(self.completer)

    # connect signals
    self.lineEdit().textEdited.connect(self.pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString)
    self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)


# on selection of an item from the completer, select the corresponding item from combobox 
def on_completer_activated(self, text):
    if text:
        index = self.findText(text)
        self.setCurrentIndex(index)
        self.activated[str].emit(self.itemText(index))


# on model change, update the models of the filter and completer as well 
def setModel(self, model):
    super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModel(model)
    self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(model)
    self.completer.setModel(self.pFilterModel)


# on model column change, update the model column of the filter and completer as well
def setModelColumn(self, column):
    self.completer.setCompletionColumn(column)
    self.pFilterModel.setFilterKeyColumn(column)
    super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModelColumn(column) 

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.initUI()


def initUI(self):


    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
    self.setWindowTitle('Tennis Form')
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Project-Tennis/Tennis-icon.png'))   

    button1 = QPushButton("ATP", self)
    button1.resize(350,50)
    button1.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod1)
    button1.move(225, 200)   

    button2 = QPushButton("WTA", self)
    button2.resize(350,50)
    button2.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod2)
    button2.move(225, 275)

    self.select = Select_player(self)

def clickMethod1(self):
    import pandas as pd
    import pickle
    df = pd.read_pickle('C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Project-Tennis/ATP_Rankings.pickle')
    self.my_list = df["Name"].tolist()
    self.select.show()

def clickMethod2(self):
    import pandas as pd
    import pickle
    df = pd.read_pickle('C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Project-Tennis/WTA_Rankings.pickle')
    self.my_list = df["Name"].tolist()
    self.select.show()

class Select_player(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Select_player,self).__init__()       
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
    self.setWindowTitle('Select Players')
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Project-Tennis/Tennis-icon.png'))

    self.player1 = ExtendedComboBox(self)
    self.player1.resize(350,25)
    self.player1.move(225, 200)
    self.player1.addItems(mainWin.my_list)

    self.player2 = ExtendedComboBox(self)
    self.player2.resize(350,25)
    self.player2.move(225, 275)
    self.player2.addItems(mainWin.my_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWin = MainWindow()
mainWin.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run the code I get the error "name 'mainWin' is not defined" and I cannot wrap my head around why it is displaying that error.

The program seems to be caused by the lines "self.player1.addItems(mainWin.my_list)" and "self.player2.addItems(mainWin.my_list)" as the code displays the windows when removing those lines.

What should be replaced so that the code can work?

Comment: Replace `mainWin.my_list` with `parent.my_list` or `self.parent().my_list`.

Answer (score 0):

You reference mainWin before declaring it. Like so:

```
self.player2.addItems(mainWin.my_list)

mainWin = MainWindow()
```

Any time you create an instance of your `Select_player` class, when it initializes, it requires a definition for `mainWin`, but mainWin doesn't exist yet, so you'll need to move your definition ahead of any Select_player object declarations.

You should be able to fix this by moving your `mainWin = MainWindow()` line above your `Select_player` class definition. Alternatively, you could just add that line + `mainWin.Show()` to the beginning of your `Select_player` class constructor

Comment: I have tried both and I still get the same problem.

Comment: Well the problem is `MainWindow.Select` relies on your `Select_Player` class being defined before the `MainWindow` class, but `SelectPlayer.PlayerX.additem(mainWin)` relies on an instance of your `MainWindow` class to be declared first, which obviously can't be declared before your `MainWindow` class is defined. So both resources rely on each other. Fix this and you'll be good to go.